# Yii2 Active record working: How i can query through relation in yii2 model

Tags: yii2, active-record-query

Here is my Restaurents model:

```
class Restaurents extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public function rules(){
        return [
            [['name'], 'string'],
        ];
    }
    public function getRestaurentInfo(){
        return $this->hasOne(RestaurentInfo::className(), ['restaurent_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

and my RestaurentInfo model:

```
class RestaurentInfo extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
public function rules(){
        return [
            [['address',], 'string']
        ];
    }
    public function getRestaurent()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Restaurens::className(), ['id' =>         'restaurent_id']);
     }
}
```

I want to query a list of restaurents with conditions:
the restaurent have name like $key or the restaurent have address like $key.

How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$restaurents = Restaurent::find()
    ->joinWith('restaurentInfo')
    ->where(['like', 'name', $key])
    ->orWhere(['like', 'address', $key])
    ->all();
```

I'd recommend to spend some time and understand how to work with [Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html) and Active Query.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it too, but result had been returned that are not what i need.
I want to query a list of restaurents, that have a name like $key , or address like $key. How i can do it

Comment: @DuyMuu This code does exactly what you described according to your data structure.